# Function doesn't return sum() in for loop

Tags: r

I have a small function to count up the number of complete observations in some files, as follows:

```
complete <- function(id = 1:332) {
   files <- list.files(pattern="*.csv")[id]
   nobs_v <- vector(mode="integer")
     for (i in length(id)){
       nobs_v[i] <- sum(complete.cases(read.csv(files[i])))
     }
   nobs_df <- data.frame(id = id, nobs = nobs_v)
   return(nobs_df)
}
```

With complete(c(1,4,5) I'm getting:

```
  id nobs
1  1   NA
2  4   NA
3  5  402
```

But files 1 and 4 contain hundreds of clean records. Can anyone spot where I screwed up?

Comment: Look at what ` i in length(id) ` actually contains.

Comment: You are a life saver.  Thank you for the fast response. 1:length(id). Got it.

Comment: You're welcome. It's also a troubleshooting tip for the rest of your coursera homework. Ik things don't behave like you expected, check whether they are/do/hold what you think they are/do /hold.